# How to get the dataItem of edited cell in kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

My problem is how I can get the dataItem(row) where a cell was updated.
The column is a dropdown menu.

It seems dataBind is not functioning well.

I am using kendo grid and angularjs in this project.

Here is a sample [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/EvEnEQaX).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `change` `event` of grid *dataSource* there you can get the current modified *dataItem* with updated *data*

```
change:function(event) {

}
```

In the above code `event` will be having the updated *dataItem*